# TypeError: Object not iterable - Django create/get

Tags: django, django-models

I've been encountering this issue for some time today, and a permanent solution would be helpful.

I have a Vendor object defined as

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
  vendor_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
  demo_vendor = models.IntegerField()
  url = models.CharField(max_length = 100L, null = True)
  logo = models.CharField(max_length = 100L, null = True)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField()
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'txn_vendors'
```

In a view, I'm implementing a form to allow for creating new vendors along with updating existing ones.  To do this, I had to implement a `getVendorData` method, which required serializing the data in JSON before sending to the client.

```
serialized = serializers.serialize("json", Vendors.objects.filter(vendor_id = incomingData["id"]))
```

In that view, if I use `filter` in place of `get`, I don't get a `TypeError : Vendors is not iterable` message.

To implement create and update functionality in one method, I wrote

```
def saveVendorData(request):
  incomingData = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get("data", None))

  if incomingData is not None:
    vendor = None
    newVendor = False

    if incomingData["id"] == "":
      vendor = Vendors.objects.create(vendor_name = incomingData["vendor_name"], demo_vendor = False, date_created = datetime.now(), url = incomingData["vendor_url"], logo = None)
      newVendor = True
    else:
      vendor = Vendors.objects.get(vendor_id = incomingData["id"])
      vendor.vendor_name = incomingData["vendor_name"]
      vendor.url = incomingData["vendor_url"]

      vendor.save()

    serialized = serializers.serialize("json", vendor)

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"success" : "true", "new_vendor" : newVendor, "data" : serialized}), mimetype = "application/json")

  else:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"success" : "false", "message" : "Issue with data reception in server"}))
```

When I try to create a new Vendors object with valid data, I get the `TypeError` response detailed above and generating this stacktrace:

```
Vendor Data: [{"pk": 5, "model": "app.vendors", "fields": {"url": "nurturing seniors", "demo_vendor": 1, "vendor_name": "NURTURING SENIORS", "date_created": null, "logo": null}}]
[15/Aug/2013 20:38:01] "POST /getVendorData/ HTTP/1.1" 200 218

Internal Server Error: /saveVendorData/

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/media/Storage/code_projects/Rowdmap_Uboat/app/taxonomy_views.py", line 272, in saveVendorData
serialized = serializers.serialize("json", vendor)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 99, in serialize
s.serialize(queryset, **options)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 42, in serialize
for obj in queryset:

TypeError: 'Vendors' object is not iterable
```

I need to send this data to the client, since creating a new Vendors record results in the insertion of a new HTML element in several locations in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error happens because the second param of `serialize` method is a QuerySet.
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data)

`get` returns a Model instande, but `filter` returns a QuerySet

> The arguments to the serialize function are the format to serialize
>   the data to (see Serialization formats) and a QuerySet to serialize.

You could write something like:

```
serialized = serializers.serialize("json", [vendor])
```